# XMLDocument, XMLTextWriter and HttpWebResponse Class will not work in .NET Core project

Tags: c#, .net-core, xmldocument, xmltextwriter

I am trying to integrate A  console app project into to a.netcore project. In my console app the project does exactly what I want it to do and build and run perfectly well but when copied into the .net core web application when I try to add the library references it is suggesting a completely different library from the ones I am using the console app. when I try to use the suggested libraries the project will not build or if I am using the exact same reference it will not work in the .net core web app.

```
private HttpWebResponse PutOnUri(string uri, string contentType, string body)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] bodyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);

        var client = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
        client.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        client.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;

        client.Method = "PUT";
        client.ContentType = contentType;
        client.ContentLength = bodyBytes.Length;

        client.GetRequestStream().Write(bodyBytes, 0, bodyBytes.Length);
        return (HttpWebResponse)client.GetResponse();
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
        return (HttpWebResponse)e.Response;
    }
}


 private XmlDocument LoadXMLFromUri(string uri)
 {
     XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
     doc.Load(uri);
     return doc;
 }

 private string ConvertXmlDocumentToString(XmlDocument doc)
 {
     StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
     XmlTextWriter tx = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
     doc.WriteTo(tx);
     return sw.ToString();
 }
```

These are the reference I am using in the OLD Console app and it works fine:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
```

Additional functions (Uses XPAth):

```
private string GetValueFromDocumentByXPath(XmlDocument doc, string xpath)
{
    var nav = doc.CreateNavigator();
    var it = nav.Select(xpath, nameSpaceManager_);
    if (it.MoveNext())
    {
        return it.Current.Value;
    }

        return "";
    }

    private void SetValueToDocumentByXPath(XmlDocument doc, string xpath, string value)
    {
        var nav = doc.CreateNavigator();
        var it = nav.Select(xpath, nameSpaceManager_);
        if (it.MoveNext())
        {
            it.Current.SetValue(value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: what version of .net-core are you targeting? The release 1.1 doesn't support some of the API you're using.

Comment: is your uri a web address?

Comment: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc (1.0.1)

Comment: @Vijay yes http://127.0.0.1:5555/dir1/dir2 

  client.AllowAutoRedirect = false; No extension method for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to modify your code a bit.

```
    private XPathDocument LoadXMLFromUri(string uri)
    {
        var req = WebRequest.CreateHttp(uri);
        var resTask = req.GetResponseAsync();
        resTask.Wait();
        XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(resTask.Result.GetResponseStream());
        return doc;
    }

    private string ConvertXmlDocumentToString(XmlDocument doc)
    {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        XmlWriter tx = XmlWriter.Create(sw);
        doc.WriteTo(tx);
        return sw.ToString();
    }

    private string GetValueFromDocumentByXPath(XPathDocument doc, string xpath)
    {
        var nav = doc.CreateNavigator();
        var it = nav.Select(xpath, nameSpaceManager_);
        if (it.MoveNext())
        {
            return it.Current.Value;
        }

        return "";
    }

    private void SetValueToDocumentByXPath(XPathDocument doc, string xpath, string value)
    {
        var nav = doc.CreateNavigator();
        var it = nav.Select(xpath, nameSpaceManager_);
        if (it.MoveNext())
        {
            it.Current.SetValue(value);
        }
    }

    private HttpWebResponse PutOnUri(string uri, string contentType, string body)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] bodyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);

            var client = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
            client.Method = "PUT";
            client.ContentType = contentType;
            var reqStreamTask = client.GetRequestStreamAsync();
            reqStreamTask.Result.Write(bodyBytes, 0, bodyBytes.Length);
            reqStreamTask.Wait();
            var resTask = client.GetResponseAsync();
            resTask.Wait();
            return (HttpWebResponse) resTask.Result;
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            return (HttpWebResponse)e.Response;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This resolves the error but I had to use System.Xml.Linq; but another error appears when using: doc.CreateNavigator()

Comment: In that case use XPathDocument. You will need to different Library. Your posted code did not indicate what you needed.

Comment: I am not sure what I need because I do not understand the problem. I am using Xpath to query a document from the URL Edit Some elements then send Put back to the Url.

Comment: I am assuming In order for my existing app to work I would have to modify the majority of my code to something else maybe LINQ with XML because these libraries aren't supported?

Comment: I have added my other two functions that stop working

Comment: @Decoder94 Edited the answer to reflect your additional methods.

Comment: Thanks!! That Compiled very well. I just need to address the HTTPWebResponse function now to be up and running There might be other ways of sending the request So I'll research how to add to your answer then mark as answered. Thanks @Vijay

Comment: @Decoder94 I have added that one too. I missed to copy it from my test soln. Small tweaks will be needed as I did not configure my server to accept PUT.

Comment: Thanks @Vijay Works Well... Can the document returned from  elementCollectionEntryDoc() be used in  ConvertXmlDocumentToString as a parameter?

Comment: Thanks! It all Work now Fixed the parameter Issue. XPATH documents are not modifiable but that a separate issue